# No sound when I play a video with a media player, but there is sound when I watch videos with a web browser. How to solve this problem?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, audio, media-player

When I play a video with a media player, there is no sound. But when I watch videos on the Internet, there is sound. What's wrong with my computer? How to solve this problem? My system is windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a codec issue.  Windows XP comes with limited codecs.  Install [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) and have it analyse the video file.  It will tell you if you're missing an audio or video codec required to play the file.

If you are missing a codec, install the [Combined Community Codec Pack](http://www.cccp-project.net/).  This will give you the codecs for most popular audio and video formats.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to get VLC which is free and supports different video extension such as mkv, avi, dvix, wma, mp4 etc.... Even if you decide to correct or update your video codec it doesn't help you playing other files. You're almost best to find a third party program such as VLc that can support all different formating and codecs.

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

hope that helps